# Pure CSS Drop Down Menu (Submenus Can't Escape Div Tag)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I've already checked the 10 or so posts that seem to be asking the same question, but without a lot of clarity.

I've created a Pure CSS Drop Down menu with five options. Two of these options (Options 2 and 3) contain their own submenus:

```css
#topnav_frame {
  color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1);
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 1);
}
#topnav {
  min-width: 1200px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0em auto;
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: .75em;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
#topnav ul.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#topnav ul.menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
}
#topnav ul.menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  margin-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
#topnav ul.menu li.submenu ul.hidden li a {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: left;
}
#topnav ul.menu li.submenu ul.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
#topnav ul.menu li.submenu:hover ul.hidden {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#topnav ul.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(105, 105, 105, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav_frame">
  <div id="topnav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="submenu"><a href="">Option 1</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href="">View Option 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Edit Option 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="submenu"><a href="">Option 2</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href="">Current Option 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Option 2 History</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Option 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Option 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS Fiddle can be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/IamHoneyBadger/mv8m1ayv/).

The problem arises when I place the mouse over the li.submenu. The menu drops down, however the menu drops down "inside" of the div, as opposed to "outside" of the div. The topnav overflow is hidden, so the scrollbar becomes visible. I would like the submenus to pop "outside" if the div.

I've already changed the z-index to reflect this required change (z-index:0 for the topnav frames and z-index: 1000 for both the ul menu and the the submenu.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't even find the drop-downs appearing!!!

Answer (score 1):

That works as expected : you set `overflow:auto` on `#topnav` element. **If you go hover option 2 or 3 and scroll down, .submenu appears.**

Just remove it. You'll have to make a different clearfix.

```
#topnav {
min-width: 1200px;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0em auto;
/* overflow: auto; */
zoom: 1;
font-size: .75em;
padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

*FYI, `overflow:auto` makes the inner element that are out of the container not visible, you have to scroll to see it. See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow*

Comment: I've become accustomed to creating two divs: an outer div that floods 100% of the screen with a background color and an inner div that has a specified with of about 1000px and "margin: 0em auto;". I wish to find a way to keep this form factor while allowing the submenus to pop out of this same form factor? Is this virtually impossible?

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction. It turns out that I had to remove the "overflow: auto" and add the "display: inline-block" attribute. Now everything works just fine. Thanks again!

Comment: To answer your question : no, there is no way to allow a child element pass through the overflow limit of a parent. You just have to deal with it.